# How can I force compliance with a given schema in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, schema, xmlreader

Let's say I have a schema with which I want an input document to comply. I load the file according to the schema like this:

```
// Load the ABC XSD
var schemata = new XmlSchemaSet();
string abcSchema = FooResources.AbcTemplate;
using (var reader = new StringReader(abcSchema))
using (var schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
{
    schemata.Add(string.Empty, schemaReader);
}

// Load the ABC file itself
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    CheckCharacters = true,
    CloseInput = false,
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
    IgnoreComments = true,
    Schemas = schemata,
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
    ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
};

XDocument inputDoc;
try
{
    using (var docReader = XmlReader.Create(configurationFile, settings))
    {
        inputDoc = XDocument.Load(docReader);
    }
}
catch (XmlSchemaException xsdViolation)
{
    throw new InvalidDataException(".abc file format constraint violated.", xsdViolation);
}
```

This works fine in detecting trivial errors in the file. However, because the schema is locked to a namespace, a document like the following is invalid, but sneaks through:

```xml
<badDoc xmlns="http://Foo/Bar/Bax">
  This is not a valid document; but Schema doesn't catch it
  because of that xmlns in the badDoc element.
</badDoc>
```

I would like to say that only the namespaces for which I have schemata should pass schema validation.

Answer (score 2):

As stupid as it seems, the thing you want to look at is actually on the `XmlReaderSettings` object:

```
settings.ValidationEventHandler += 
    (node, e) => Console.WriteLine("Bad node: {0}", node);
```

Comment: @codekaizen - hah, fair enough, that's a "better" example, although I did like the implied astonishment of my original :)

Comment: Agreed, but there may be some reason (e.g. not trashing the whole stack and the parse state) for it, though since it is hardly non-astonishing I hope the epithet "stupid" will take all the responsibility for highlighting this twist.

Comment: @codekaizen That is exceedingly diplomatic of you; Respect achieved. :)

Comment: This still seems to let the invalid document pass. But at least there's a notification. Unfortunately this causes valid cases to fail; for instance, the namespace `xml` is defined implicitly in XML, so any valid uses of `xml:space` in the document fail validation this way.

Comment: @billy-oneal Oh, there's another flag on the settings where you can tell it to ignore certain namespaces - when I get back to my desk I'll look it up.

Comment: @BillyONeal Hey, try adding this?  `ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes`

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up settling on is to basically check that the root node is in the namespace I expect. If it isn't, then I treat that the same way I treat a true schema validation failure:

```
// Parse the bits we need out of that file
var rootNode = inputDoc.Root;
if (!rootNode.Name.NamespaceName.Equals(string.Empty, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    throw new InvalidDataException(".abc file format namespace did not match.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the ReportValidationWarnings flag. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidationflags.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags.aspx.

Comment: Didn't work. Still lets the invalid document pass. Updated example code accordingly.